# send Firebase notification from another app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any possible way to invoke `onMessageReceived` from `FirebaseMessagingService` with code in `MainActivity.java` from another package (apk) without using Firebase APIs or connecting to FCM Server?

`MyFirebaseMessagingService.java`

```java
public final class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
         // I'm interested in this method
    }

    public void onNewToken(String str) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your use case for doing this?  There are almost certainly better ways of implementing this, if it's a legit use case (and not just trying to spam another app with messages that it shouldn't get).

Comment: I work as an Application Security Engineer. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to exploit our app using this method I searched and read the docs however I didn't found any cases like the one I'm trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to read the documentation for [FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver).  This is the BroadcastReceiver that receives push messages from FCM.  It's merged in the manifest like this:

```
 <receiver
     android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
     android:exported="true"
     android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
         <category android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

As stated in that documentation:

> The `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND` permission is held by Google Play services. This prevents other apps from invoking the broadcast receiver.

So, unless your code is running in the Google Play services app process, or some other similar process installed via root access that has the required permission, it's not going to be possible to forcibly deliver a message.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling REST API from your `MainActivity.java` of another package. API documentation can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#rest). Provide proper server key to send FCM to your another package's app.